# MAX31855 Thermocouple trouble

Tags: arduino

I got the example from adafruit run MAX31855 Thermocouple example.
    But the result I got was below. It has problem on my code or problem on setting up the device ..

Please help !I tried long time to google but cannot find the result

```
Internal Temp = 0.00
C = 0.00
F = 32.00
Internal Temp = 0.00
C = 0.00
F = 32.00
Internal Temp = 0.00
C = 0.00
F = 32.00
Internal Temp = 0.00
C = 0.00
F = 32.00

Here is the code

/*************************************************** 
  This is an example for the Adafruit Thermocouple Sensor w/MAX31855K

  Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit Thermocouple Sensor
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/products/269

  These displays use SPI to communicate, 3 pins are required to  
  interface
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.  
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

    #include <Adafruit_MAX31855.h>

    int thermoDO = 3;
    int thermoCS = 4;
    int thermoCLK = 5;

    Adafruit_MAX31855 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      Serial.println("MAX31855 test");
      // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
      delay(500);
    }

    void loop() {
      // basic readout test, just print the current temp
       Serial.print("Internal Temp = ");
       Serial.println(thermocouple.readInternal());

       double c = thermocouple.readCelsius();
       if (isnan(c)) {
         Serial.println("Something wrong with thermocouple!");
       } else {
         Serial.print("C = "); 
         Serial.println(c);
       }
       Serial.print("F = ");
       Serial.println(thermocouple.readFarenheit());



delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: This does sound like an SPI problem. Check the port pins input output directions are correct. Also the idle polarity you have set for your spi bus. What would be ideal would be to see oscilloscope traces of chip-select and SCK and SDO SDI.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts, obviously it is **not** freezing in your room, but the thermocouple does return the correct relation between 0C and 32F, without any data conversion on your part.

So, does the thermocouple have a physical reference point or junction that has to connected somewhere along with the thermocouple device itself?

Does the documentation say it always returns 0C/32F when there is an error of some type?

Finally, are your SPI pins correct? Remember, there are specific pins on the Arduino for SPI are you using those pins?